# How to refer to self in pandas subsetting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filter, series

When I'm exploring data in an ad hoc way, I often have code like this:

```
X = (adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1)
print(X[X > 0])
```

Is there a way to do this in a single line in an easy way? The following works but is verbose:

```
(adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1)[(adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1) > 0]
```

I want something like this:

```
(adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1)[self > 0]
```

Note that this isn't production code. It is part of ad hoc exploration where iteration speed is important to results, which is why I wish to be able to do this common thing in a single line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pipe`:

```py
(adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1).pipe(lambda x: x[x>0])
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the many uses of `.loc` is exactly this. You can pass it a lambda function, which will take the dataframe as a parameter and return a mask to filter by:

```
(adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1).loc[lambda x:x>0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try [walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) introduced in Python 3.8

```py
# Thanks for richardec pointing out list symbol [] is not necessary here
df, res = [(x := (adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1)), x[x>0]]

# or

res = (x := (adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1))[x>0]
```

Comment: I think you can remove the surrounding `[` and `]`: `df, res = [(x := (adj_all.o.diff(1) / adj_none.o.diff(1)).diff(1)), x[x>0]]`